# Перестала грузить статика django

Tags: django, static

На локальном сервере перестала грузить вся статика (css, js, картинки и тд). Попробовал перейти по пути в папку static и открыть в ней что-нибудь - не получается. Папка static находится на уровне со всеми приложениями.

### settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.152', '.pythonanywhere.com' ]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'phonenumber_field',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {

        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Пробовал это в **urls.py** вставить - ничего не изменилось:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Причем media-файлы работают. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Если вы решили нарушать каноны Django и помещать статику в нестандартное место («на уровне со всеми приложениями»), то нужно это самое место прописать в списке STATICFILES_DIRS, иначе Django просто не будет знать где искать файлы

Comment: И конечно же это место ни в коем случае не должно совпадать со STATIC_ROOT, так как у STATIC_ROOT совершенно другое предназначениe: Django не читает файлы из STATIC_ROOT, а наоборот помещает в STATIC_ROOT файлы из других мест (в том числе из STATICFILES_DIRS) при выполнении команды collectstatic

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, заработало